# How to auto generate sequence number in HTML textbox by clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html

How to auto generate sequence number in HTML text box by clicking on button.

[image]

Comment: By the beard of Zeus, who upvoted this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a sequence number.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<input id="demo" type="text">


<script>
var seq=0;
function myFunction() {
seq=seq+1;
    document.getElementById("demo").value = seq;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```